# How to install ipkg (or opkg) package manager on Synology DiskStation

Tags: linux, ssh, nas

Is there anybody out there who got the `ipkg` (or `opkg`) package manager running on a Synology DS412+ with DSM 4.3, or someone who knows how to do so?

I've tried to install by GUI, used the package from 'quadrat4', but a modal message occurred that it can't be installed properly.
Next I tried to install via SSH as 'root'. I was following the few step-by-step tutorials I've found around the internet. But none of these variants will work for me.

```
cd /volume1/tmp
wget http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/syno-i686/cross/unstable/syno-i686-bootstrap_1.2-7_i686.xsh
chmod +x syno-i686-bootstrap_1.2-7_i686.xsh
sh syno-i686-bootstrap_1.2-7_i686.xsh
cd /
ln -s /volume1/@optware /opt
cd /
vi /etc/profile
    #PATH=/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:$PATH
vi /root/.profile
    #PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/syno/sbin:/usr/syno/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
    #export PATH
reboot
```

After doing all the steps as described, I just get:

```
ipkg update
-ash: ipkg: not found
```

Hope you can help me out with this!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to comment out `#PATH=/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:$PATH` in your /etc/profile, you need that path to use the `ipkg` command.

Also try `ls /opt/bin/` to see if ipkg has really been installed.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Medium article from September 1, 2019 that suggests installing `opkg` (or `ipkg` for older DiskStation models) with *Easy Bootstrap Installer* from a custom source:

> *The Most famous lite weight package managers are ipkg and opkg.
>   ipkg is considered dead. So I recommend everyone to use opkg instead.*

[How To Install a Package Manager on a Synology NAS/Router (ipkg/oPKG)](https://medium.com/@yehia2amer/how-to-install-a-package-manager-on-a-synology-nas-router-ipkg-opkg-c620890e4c77)

**I tried this today on my ancient Synology DiskStation 212+ and it couldn't install `opkg` because the Linux kernel is too old for the DS 212+, but the software referred to in the article can also install `ipkg`, and that worked in my case.**

It looks like old DiskStation models don't upgrade their Linux kernel at some point.

Comment: Easy Bootstrap Installer is not working for DSM7 users anymore due to changes in package format as discussed on EBI maintenance forum https://www.synology-forum.de/threads/ebi-easy-bootstrap-installer.68335/post-949587

Answer (score 0):

In 2018 (DSM6) is better to use opkg. Anyway both can be installed with:

Install ipkg - https://chattim.wordpress.com/2016/05/08/install-ipkg-on-synology-via-gui/

```
1. Package Center>Settings>Package source 
2. add https://www.cphub.net/
3. search pkg
4. install EasyBootstrapInstaller > oPkg
5. don't install iPKGui is blocking the UI
6. reboot
7. sudo su -
8. root:~# opkg
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why opkg is better?

Comment: I don't remember. But a search on google on `ipgk vs opkg` gives a lot of reasons like "he reason for creating opkg was that ipkg was an effectively a dead end
project (not dead, just a dead end). OE has had ipkg patches sitting
around for years and there was no active ipkg maintainer and no active
ipkg development. I was perfectly happy to see ipkg being renamed and
development continued under a new banner."

Comment: Or "The opkg utility is the lightweight package manager used for this job. Opkg is a fork of ipkg, the package manager used in NSLU2's Optware, which is designed to add software to stock firmware of embedded devices.
Opkg is a full package manager for the root file system, including kernel modules and drivers, while ipkg is just a way to add software to a separate directory (e.g. /opt)."

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore (DSM7), it is blocked due to requiring root

Comment: Easy Bootstrap Installer is not working for DSM7 users anymore due to changes in package format as discussed on EBI maintenance forum https://www.synology-forum.de/threads/ebi-easy-bootstrap-installer.68335/post-949587

Answer (score 0):

[Use opkg instead of ipkg on Synology](https://www.beatificabytes.be/use-opkg-instead-of-ipkg-on-synology/) might be useful

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

For okpg (entware) please follow this guide: https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki/Install-on-Synology-NAS

I have just verified it on Synology DS418j (Realtek RTD1293 / aarch64) running DSM 7.0-41882.